# Moving div's with CSS that have a GIF inside. The GIF pauses while moving

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gif

http://dev.epicwebdesign.ca/dontsue/

I'm making a mortal kombat clone with jQuery. I have basic things hardwired right now, like moving, jumping and punch and kick with a and s. They will all be passed through a timer like with a normal game, the hardwiring is just temporary.

I am putting characters in a "hitbox" div. The character is represented by an image. This image is an animated gif for walking and for standing, and images for kicks and punches.

For some reason, the gif pauses while the character is walking via .css('left' +/- =15px). It plays once, then stops. It has nothing to do with walking per se, just that the div is moving.

Any ideas?

Comment: if you are making a game, maybe it would be easier to use a canvas element?

Comment: I haven't really been able to find a good explanation of the canvas element. Is it handled differently? I was under the understanding it's just a semantic thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canvas gives you a 2d paint area to draw things on. Here is an intro to it based on creating a game:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/notearsgame/

There exists also alot of third party game libs that are based on Canvas, like ImpactJS:

http://impactjs.com/